# How to create a new column and add values to it based on a condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
alter table marks
add divisible_by_tenvarchar(50) default 'null'
SELECT marks, divisible_by_ten, IF(marks %10 =0 , "yes", "no");
```

this code

I have tried the above code and surely there is a mistake.
there are two columns studentID and marks. and I need to arrange them in student ID order and also create a new column and say "yes" or "no" if marks are divisible by 10.

Comment: if the default is "null", just first add the column, and then run an update query no?

Comment: Is your table called `marks`? In that table, do you also have a column called `marks`?

Comment: Yes the table name is marks and also there is one column called marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this first:

```
alter table marks add divisible_by_ten char(3);
```

Then, update data in it:

```
alter table marks add divisible_by_ten char(3);
update marks
set divisible_by_ten = case when marks % 10 = 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end;
```

## Example

```
create table marks (marks int);
insert into marks values (10), (11);
alter table marks add divisible_by_ten char(3);
update marks
set divisible_by_ten = case when marks % 10 = 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end;
select * from marks;
```

**Result**

> ```
> marks | divisible_by_ten
> ----: | :---------------
>    10 | yes             
>    11 | no
> ```

See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=85e32cde86e13e05bf2c1fdaa3fbdf7e

## Alternate

You don't really have to create a field to store that divisible information. If marks change, you will have to update divisible column manually or programmatically or put a trigger on the table.

Instead, don't add divisible column. Just create a view.

```
create view marks_10 as 
select
  marks, 
  case when marks % 10 = 0 then 'yes' else 'no' end as divisible_by_10
from marks;
```

Then, you can call the view at any point to get fresh data along with divisible_by_10 dynamic column like this:

```
select * from marks_10;
```

Example of that: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4370997be4c64fd89908f8f35fe95fda

Comment: Thank you So Much for the details and explanation. IT worked.@zedfoxus

Comment: @SachinAttri awesome. You are welcome. I noticed that you have asked other questions as well in the past. You can put closure to your question by accepting an answer. You can do that by clicking on a check mark by the answer of your choice.